# Jquery two .get() functions working differently

Tags: jquery, image, canvas, get

The first `.get()` function works properly in all browsers and the second one only works every time in Firefox, about every second time in Chrome and not at all in IE.

The code is wrapped in a `$(document).ready` function, so it should not be a problem with the page loading.

The first `.get()` function gets recent news from a RSS feed and posts them in a `<ul>`.
The second `.get()` function gets the same things from a different RSS feed and posts them in a similar way, but the difference is that it also gets image sources and I'm drawing these images into `<canvas>` elements in the last part of the code.

Even without drawing the images into canvas elements, and without getting the image sources, the second .get() function does not work every time in Chrome and never in IE. The first one works every time in all browsers.

I am also using a similar piece of code to draw some other images into canvas elements, and it works properly everywhere and everytime.

```
//The first, working .get() function:
$.get("rss-url", function (data) {
    var $xml = $(data);
    var $i = 0;
    $xml.find("item").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            item = {
                title: $this.find("title").text(),
                link: $this.find("guid").text(),
                pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
            }
        //Do something with item here...
        if ($i < 10) {
            var pv = new Date(item.pubDate).toLocaleString();
            $("#uutiset_latest > ul").append("<li><a href=" + item.link + ">" + item.title + "</a><br>" + pv + "</li>");
        }
        $i++;
    });
});


//Second, not so working .get() function:

$(function () {
    var img0, img1, img2;
    $.get("rss-url", function (data) {
        var $xml = $(data);
        var $i = 0;
        $xml.find("item").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                item = {
                    title: $this.find("title").text(),
                    link: $this.find("guid").text(),
                    pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                    pic: $this.find("description").html()
                }
            if ($i < 3) {
                var pv = new Date(item.pubDate).toLocaleString();
                var parsed = $('<div/>').html(item.pic);
                var picSrc = parsed.find("img").attr("src");
                $("#right_column_feed > ul").append("<li><a href=" + item.link + ">" + item.title + "</a><div id='tsemppi_div" + $i.toString() + "'><canvas id='tsemppi_canvas" + $i.toString() + "' width='150' height='100' class='tsemppi_canvas'></canvas></div>" + pv + "</li>");
            }
            switch ($i) {
                case 0: img0 = picSrc; break;
                case 1: img1 = picSrc; break;
                case 2: img2 = picSrc; break;
            }
            $i++;
        });
        drawImages2();
    });

//the function to draw the images into <canvas> elements:

    function drawImages2() {
        var imgWidth = 150;
        var imgHeight = 100;
        var $z = 0;

        $(".tsemppi_canvas").each(function () {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("tsemppi_canvas" + $z.toString()).getContext("2d");
            var canvImage = new Image();
            canvImage.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(canvImage, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            }
            switch ($z) {
                case 0: canvImage.src = (img0); break;
                case 1: canvImage.src = (img1); break;
                case 2: canvImage.src = (img2); break;
            }
            $z++;
        });
    };
});
```

All these function are in the same .js file, the images, webpage and rss feeds are on the same server as the .js file.

Comment: As you said - second `get()` use different RSS feed - maybe there is the problem. Have you try first `get()` with second RSS and second `get()` with first RSS ?

Comment: If I swap the rss-urls, the functionality does not change. The first one works and second one works as described before.

Comment: So problem is not data from RSS and not `get()` but your code in `function (data){...}`. You can use `alert()` to test variables in your code. Maybe they get not what you expect. If you use firebug you can use `console.log("some text")` in your code to see result in firebug console - it is more comfortable than `alert()`.

Comment: The variables are all ok, and it works perfectly in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, it was this line:

```
pic: $this.find("description").html()
```

I changed it to get the text, not the html and now it works in every browser:

```
pic: $this.find("description").text()
```